# Passing data from one page to another and refresh the main page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html

I have a small problem that gives me headaches already. We have two opened pages.In the first one (let's call it MAIN PAGE) is a video streaming. In the second page (let's call it BACK OFFICE) is a form where an user can choose between live and offline streaming. What I need is when I'm updating the form in BO the MAIN PAGE to refresh itself automatically. I think Java and Ajax can do this trick but I can't figure it out how. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need to you Socket. AJAX will require continues requests. You take parts from this https://hub.adama.io/ajax-socket/ if you are willing to use AJAX

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I have a question though. At "url" what variable should I use?

Comment: if main is opened by back office and if they are in the same domain, you can use postMessage

Comment: You don't need any `url`, you can use `location.href.reload()` or `location.reload()`

Comment: @Regis Portalez The main page (index.php) is always open. The BO page (admin.php) is accessed trough a smartphone. Both are in the same domain, on a local network. When a change is made in BO the main page have to refresh automatically.

Comment: @ Adam Azad thanks for your solution, is very useful but not for this particular project. I have only two files hosted on a PC under XAMP environment. With Socket is a little to complicated for this. I don't care about requests because I just want the main page to be refreshed when something is changed in BO. The idea of this project is to stream a video (live or offline), just that.